# Firefox esr shows webpage only as text

Tags: firefox, browser, raspberry-pi

i have a problem with Firefox-esr on my raspberry pi 3+ with raspbian where amazon is displayed purely as text.

[Screenshot of the raspberry pi desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjAeW.png)

Here are the things i've already tried, sadly without any results thus far:

What i already tried:

- Changed DNS (Google, Cloudflare and OpenDNS)
- Cleared Cache & Cookies. Reset Firefox completely
- Re-Installed Firefox
- Tried it on a fresh installation of Resbian
- Tried Version 52 and 60 of FF
- Changed the Theme of the Browser
- Tweaked some settings

Any help appriecated

Comment: Does it work on other devices on your network?

Comment: Do you have Javascript blocked?

Comment: @David: Yes its even working on the raspberry itself with chromium

Comment: @fixer:no does not seems like it. Is there a way I can submit a screen shot in the comments from mobile? Otherwise I can paste the Screenshot of the settings page in a couple of hours.

Comment: @shiny, I'm not familiar with SE's mobile interface.  I know there are a few things not supported.  Try to edit the question and add a link to the image.  If you don't see the add-image icon, that will be the answer.  :-)

Comment: i've uploaded all the java preferences from the about:config page to imgur:
[Screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/AwWFArP)

Comment: something else i just discovered: any subdomain from amazon is working just fine (amazon music, partnernet, aws, etc.)

Comment: Further investigation: There seems to be a pocket pc version of amazon that might trigger: [source](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/amazon-hacks/0596005423/ch01s08.html)

Comment: ok, so there is some sort of lightweight version of amazon you can access via this link: https://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/fp.html?id=fs
sadly the the _/fullsite_ did not made any changes on the raspberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Seems like amazon is pulling the useragent string to output this lightweight version. So all i had to do was override the useragent:

1. Open a **new tab** in Firefox and type in the adress bar `about:config`
2. **Right-Click** and choose **new -> String**
3. enter the following first for the preference name `general.useragent.override`
4. Next add a user agent string. I used `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0`
5. **restart firefox** and you should be good to go

you can get your user agent string from this site: [useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/)

Thank you guys for you help.

Answer (score 1):

slight correction on the instructions to fix:

1. open a new tab in Firefox and type in the address bar>about:config
2. in the search bar, type:>general.useragent.override
3. light up the radio button for string, and then hit the "+" sign a text box will be centered for you to type.
4. cut and paste the text between the pointers:  >Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0<
5. restart firefox and you should be good to go